# Selenium can't find element when iterating through pages

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am new in this and I have been trying to use selenium to automate search for specific topics, I cannot get this to work when the page loads on the second step, I would really appreciate your help! here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import sqlite3

def get_web(busqueda):
    #obtencion de datos de pagina web
    print("Runnig: Obtencion de datos de pagina web")
    url_data = 'http://jurisprudencia.poder-judicial.go.cr/SCIJ_PJ/busqueda/jurisprudencia/jur_libre.aspx'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url_data)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_name('txtConsulta').send_keys(busqueda)
        driver.find_element_by_name('cmdBuscar').click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Texto de la sentencia').click()
        print(driver.page_source)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # seconds
        texto = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.Section1').text
        print('text: ', texto)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    driver.close()


get_web('uber')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in a frame you need to switch to first

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="MainFrame"]')) 
texto = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.Section1').text
```